# Creating an operator that dinamically updates the viewport a certain number of times per second

Tags: python, operator

I want to create an operator to preview a physic animation in real time.
I have this set of object and I wanted to move them for example using a basic equation like this:

```
locx = locx - 0.1
```

a certain number of times a frame. (The number depends on a `subframes` Variable.).
and then using `bpy.context.scene.frame_set()` move to the next frame and subframe, and while I execute operations the viewport should update (so 10 times per frame, in this case). 
The problem is that to keep a velocity that's pertinent to scene fps, the time elapsing from **x*y** operation should be **1 second**, or in case blender couldn't keep up, more. (Where **x** is subframes and **y** is scene fps.)

(I wanted to state that moving objects isn't the only thing I'd like to do, I should also create objects and delete them, which isn't exactly a fast operation as moving objects can be.)

So, in other words I would like the operator to behave a bit like the 3d view animation when set to No-Sync as scene sync setting, infact, if the scene fps are 60 it will not proceed for more than 60 frames in a time of a second.

I know not so much about real-time operators, I know you could use modal but I've never found anything useful on how tu use them.

Comment: I don't get it, why moving the objects in between frames? Notice that you can pass **subframes** to [`frame_set(frame=3, subframe=0.01)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Scene.html?highlight=frame_set#bpy.types.Scene.frame_set), that should force the scene to update automatically.

Comment: My fault, I made some errors, now should be ok.

Comment: And... the values of *your physics animation* coming in from a text file or something?

Comment: no, real time. It's like particles, I ceate a particle each frame and then animate it's location on x axis using this equation: ***"locx = locx-(0.5*g*(t^2))"***, where locx is the current location, g is 9.81 and t is (1/fps)

Comment: calculated in real-time*

Comment: You're right I just found out that Playback speed isn't consistend during time. I modified the Operator MOdal Timer to use (1/(fps*(subframes+1))) in timer_add in the execute function to use the right interval and even with that it plays at inconsistent speed. So I gouess I have to stay with that.